# Is there a way to turn cellulose into sugar at home?

Tags: organic-chemistry, home-experiment, carbohydrates, fuel

I know that once you have sugars, you can ferment, distill, and dehydrate to create 95+% ethanol. I've also read about cellulosic ethanol, with the new step there being the breakdown of the cellulose into simpler sugars.  Is there a relatively cheap way to do that yet, or it still only in expensive research labs?

Comment: If you want to do it on a small scale at home, why not just *buy* sugar: it is likely to be a lot cheaper than trying to make it from cellulose.

Comment: I'm thinking specifically about how to convert waste grass clippings into useful fuel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A method used to break down cellulose into sugars is hydrolysis :

You could use enzymes to hydrolyze the cellulose to produce glucose, but enzymes cost a lot and as you are looking for a cheap way, using enzymes is not an option. A second method is to use an acid (e.g. sulfuric acid) to produce the glucose (just google "cellulose acid hydrolysis"  and you'll find some useful links)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know of any prices online for the enzymes? I'm curious exactly how much "a lot" is.  But yes I'll look into the acid hydrolysis.

Comment: Sigma-aldrich sells enzyme solutions for around 76.9(USD) for 50ml (and for 250ml it is 211(USD))(however this varies from product to product)